# Binding to $PORT in Heroku-hosted Python web app

Tags: python, heroku, port

I recently deployed a web app to Heroku that tries to download tweets from the Twitter Streaming API.  It works for 60 seconds, but then Heroku throws the error that:

```
 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

To connect to the API, I use PycURL, a wrapper for the C library libcurl, to open a connection to the endpoint uri.  I set the local port used by PycURL to the $PORT variable assigned by Heroku.  The relevant code is the following:

```
def collect_debug_info(self, debug_type, debug_msg):
    if debug_type == 0 and debug_msg.decode('utf-8')[0] == 'L':
        print('debug(%s): %s' % (debug_type, debug_msg))

def setup_connection(self):
    # Creates persistent HTTP connection to Streaming API endpoint using cURL.
    if self.conn:
        self.conn.close()
        self.buffer = ''
    self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, API_ENDPOINT_URL)
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, USER_AGENT)
    # Using gzip is optional but saves us bandwidth.
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING, 'deflate, gzip')
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, urllib.parse.urlencode(POST_PARAMS))
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Host: stream.twitter.com',
                                         'Authorization: %s' % self.get_oauth_header()])
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.LOCALPORT, int(os.environ.get('PORT')))
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, self.collect_debug_info)
    # self.handle_tweet is the method that is called when new tweets arrive
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.handle_tweet)

    print('Port var: %s' % os.environ.get('PORT'))
```

The text returned from `collect_debug_info` is `debug(0): b'Local port: 19379\n'`

The text returned from `print('Port var: %s' % os.environ.get('PORT'))` is `Port var: 19379`

My Procfile is the following:

```
web: python3 "twitter streaming data.py"
```

"twitter streaming data.py" contains the code I posted as well as other code.

Comment: Does your application have a web interface, or is it something that should run without one, e.g. via cron?

Comment: Right now I am just running it from the Heroku Dashboard on an as-needed basis.

Comment: That's probably the problem. Heroku expects your application to run a web server bound to `$PORT`, at least for web Dynos. I doubt that worker Dynos have the same requirement. Please [edit] your question and add your `Procfile`.

Comment: Understood.  Does my command in the `Procfile` I just added to this post initiate such a web server?  I've been using that `Procfile` all along.

Comment: @Chris what if you have an app that needs web access for instance but does not have a web interface?  In my case I am using Selenium to launch Chrome and to automate some web browser tasks.

Comment: @JacekTrociński, then you shouldn't be using a `web` dyno. Use a `worker` dyno instead, by replacing `web:` with `worker:` in your `Procfile`.

Comment: @Chris a worker dyno has access to the internet?  I don't think that will work.

Comment: @Chris just tried using a worker dyno, it worked, thanks!  Someone on YouTube has been spreading fake news about only web dynos having access to the internet.